# RAID 5 en Centos 7 no funciona después de un hard reset

Tags: linux

Tengo un servidor con Centos 7 y Plesk 12 en el proveedor OVH.
RAID 5 con 3 discos. El otro día hubo un fallo en la placa madre y tuvieron que cambiarla. Al apagarse el servidor de forma abrupta, se descompuso el RAID y ahora no sé cómo volver a reactivarlo.

Puedo entrar por consola en modo rescate (con una `Debian`), pero no sé cómo volver a montar el RAID 5. Parece que los datos están ahí, pero me da miedo perderlos si voy haciendo pruebas.

He enviado tickets a OVH, pero no hacen nada.

Comment: Hasta donde llega el proceso de booteo?

Comment: No puedo verlo.Desde el panel de control de OVH lo reinicio, y me llega un mensaje de OVH diciendo que da error y no responde al ping, por lo que automáticamente lo ponen "modo rescate". Entonces puedo acceder por ssh, y veo que es una versión de Debian. En ningún momento puedo acceder por ssh a la versión de Centos que tiene el servidor, por lo que no sé hasta dónde llega el booteo. Entiendo que antes tengo que recomponer el RAID 1 donde está el root y luego el RAID5 donde están los datos

Comment: Parece ser que solo existe la partición RAID1, la RAID5 ha desaparecido. ¿Hay alguna forma de recuperar la información?  root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat  
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sdc1[2]
      61938624 blocks [3/2] [_UU]

Answer (score 0):

¿Cual el resultado completo del comando "cat /proc/mdstat"?

En OVH el modo rescate es básicamente una unidad live de Linux pero utilizan una imagen de Debian, pero el sistema de ficheros está completo y a no ser que haya problemas físicos con los discos los ficheros deberían estar ahí.